# Google 2 step authentication with AccountManager.confirmCredentials()

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-authenticator

In my app, one of the ways to enter is to login with your gmail account. I use the AccountManager.confirmCredentials() method to confirm their login details are correct.

The problem arises when the user has 2 step authentication enabled. I have no idea how to handle this case, as the confirmCredentials() method simply returns invalid.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into it a bit more, it actually just takes knowledge on the users part. Rather than using their gmail password, they must generate an app specific password and use that instead.

Comment: How do you mean, for an application that needs access to Gmail, will have to work such a way? Isnt there any way to handle the two step verification and make things easy for the user?